# Custom Controller Case Attachment

Tags: apex, controller

I'm new to SF and trying to write a custom case controller that adds 
an attachment to a case.

I've simplified my apex code below. I'm guessing I need to do a.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId(); to get the attachment to show up under the user's case list?

I would like to delete an attachment I used for a test but I can't find it.

```
public class MyCaseController {

    public Case c { get; set; }
    public Attachment a { get; set; }

    public MyCaseController() {
        c = new Case();
        a = new Attachment();        
    }

public PageReference save() {
        try {
            INSERT c;
            if (a.BodyLength > 0)
            {
                a.ParentId = c.Id;
                INSERT a;
            }
            return new PageReference('/apex/Thanks');
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }
}


<apex:page controller="MyCaseController" sidebar="False" showHeader="False">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages><br />
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Submit"/><br /><br />
        Issue type:<br />
        <apex:inputfield value="{!c.type}" required="true"/><br />
        Issue priority:<br />
        <apex:inputField value="{!c.priority}"/><br />
        Subject:<br />
        <apex:inputField value="{!c.Subject}" required="true"/><br />
        <apex:inputTextarea value="{!c.description}" rows="20" cols="20" /><br />
        Attachment:<br />
        <apex:inputFile value="{!a.body}" filename="{!a.name}" id="file"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/Simple Custom Controller to Insert an Attachment into Salesforce
public with sharing class AttachmentUploadController 
{
public String parentId {get;set;}
public Attachment attach {get;set;}

public AttachmentUploadController()
{
    attach = new Attachment();
}

//When user clicks upload button on Visualforce Page, perform upload/insert
//Redirect user to newly inserted document
public ApexPages.Pagereference upload()
 {

    //This shows how to insert an Attachment
    attach.ParentId = parentId;
    insert attach;

    return new ApexPages.Standardcontroller(attach).view();   
  }
 }

//AttachmentUpload - Visualforce Page
<apex:page controller="AttachmentUploadController">
<apex:form >
    <apex:outputText value="Parent Object ID: "/><apex:inputText value="   {!parentId}"/><br/>
    <apex:outputText value="Input File:  "/><apex:inputFile value="{!attach.body}"   filename="{!attach.name}"/><br/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Upload" action="{!upload}"/>
</apex:form>
```

Please find the above code to help you understand .

The wrong thing is i see you are inserting record twice .If you are updating parent record its update .

Comment: To help clarify - the attachment in the code I posted was intended for a new case.

Comment: Since this is the only answer, I will mark it as the answer since it helped me resolve this. Thank you.